# React Hooks - having trouble with splice updating state during onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, slice

[SANDBOX DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/splice-test-v40pp?file=/src/App.js)

Here is the snippet of my code that's running. When I console.log it looks fine, but for some reason it won't set the state. When clicking a box it should delete by using splice. I know there's a basic reason why it's failing but I can't seem to grasp it.

```js
  const handleClick = (index) => {
    const newBoxOrder = order;
    newBoxOrder.splice(index, 1);
    const newState = newBoxOrder;
    console.log(newState);
    setOrder(newState);
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/splice-test-forked-6m14g?file=/src/App.js:544-737)

```
 const handleClick = (index) => {
        const newBoxOrder = order;
        newBoxOrder.splice(index, 1);
        const newState = newBoxOrder;
        console.log(newState);
        setOrder([...newState]); 
      };
```

Comment: Gosh, the spreader of course, I feel foolish but it's all part of learning. Thanks so much!!

Comment: It looks like the state was still being updated correctly, but react wasn't re-rendering the DOM because the reference to `order` hadn't changed.

Comment: Thanks! I have a bit more to learn about references and state rendering. This helps

Comment: please have a look at this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74017672/state-not-getting-update-on-deleting-one-object-from-an-array-in-usestate